# How to display Vue-Toasted message in a particular <div> instead of using the available positions?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have already experimented with the position property available from the api....but i have a requirement to display the toast messages in a particular div instead of using provided positions.

I definitely can make a separate position class(doing this will fix the message to a particular position) and provide that but i want it to stick to the div as it may be dynamic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For this and future questions, you should show what you've attempted to solve the problem.  We can help you solve particular issues, but won't do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Unfortunately Not, you can use the `containerClass` if you need to add an extra class to the toast container. toast plugin will manipulate the toast container id with `toasted-container`.

PS : i am the dev of vue toasted ;)